# mysql query updating transactions(transactionID) that only exist(transactionID) once in other table

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to generate a mysql query similar to this:

Update TRANSACTION SET points = 0  WHERE TransactionID NOT IN(SELECT TransactionID,  COUNT(*)  FROM trans_products  GROUP BY TransactionID WHERE COUNT(*) > 1)

The point is that I need to update transactions in 'transaction' table that exist once in table 'trans_products'

Any help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE
    TRANSACTION
SET
    points = 0
WHERE
   TransactionID IN (
       SELECT 
           TransactionID
       FROM
           trans_products
       GROUP BY
           TransactionID
       HAVING
           COUNT(*) = 1
   )
```

**Edit**: per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543187/mysql-query-updating-transactionstransactionid-that-only-existtransactionid/11545416#comment15283595_11545416) of needed to add the ProductID, you can't have a `WHERE` after the `HAVING` clause. This is what you need:

```
UPDATE
    TRANSACTION
SET
    points = 0
WHERE
   TransactionID IN (
       SELECT 
           TransactionID
       FROM
           trans_products
       WHERE
           ProductID = '192'
       GROUP BY
           TransactionID
       HAVING
           COUNT(*) = 1
   )
```

Comment: yes this is what I needed thank you; in addition, In trans_products there ProductID (a transaction can have several products) , The query should be including just ProductID = '192':

Comment: The problem in this query:PDATE
    TRANSACTION
SET
    points = 0
WHERE
   TransactionID IN (
       SELECT 
           TransactionID
       FROM
           trans_products
       GROUP BY
           TransactionID
       HAVING
           COUNT(*) = 1 AND ProductID = '192' 
   ), in Group BY TransactionID not all the products are appearing so that I can filter accordingly